No se muestran backgrounds de css en mi página web ejecutada con xampp
estoy haciendo una página web donde para poner algunas imágenes en divs uso background-image:url(), lo estuve ejecutando con un servidor que descargué en Visual Code, sin embargo, hoy que lo quise ejecutar en el localhost con xampp sí me abre los archivos e importa hojas de estilo, pero no las imágenes que añado con css.
Ya añadí una variable de entorno del sistema en el path con la dirección de dónde está instalado xampp en mi laptop, el servidor corre bien, el único problema es ese de las imágenes.
La primera foto es cómo debería de verse esa página y la segunda cómo se ve con xampp. También adjuntos imágenes de la variable en el sistema.
Si pudieran ayudarme se los agradezco mucho, ya verifiqué el código de las imágenes y parece estar bien.
Aqui están dos ejemplos de cómo estoy poniendo las imágenes.
body{
background-image: url('/images/aguaindex.gif');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

.imgKax{
    background-image: url('/images/UsrKaxieBscr.png');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 290px;
    width: 230px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
}

Ya probé añadiendo la variable del sistema C:/xampp/php en Path y no me solucionó nada.

No se ven las imágenes.
Son muchas las opciones que tienes.
Lo más probable es que hayas copiado tu código dentro de la carpeta "www" o "htdocs" de Xampp, entonces accedes a ella a través de http://localhost/tuproyecto/ entonces al acceder a los recursos, entre ellos las imágenes, estás tratando de obtenerlas desde el root del servidor, o sea desde http://localhost/images/aguaindex.gif (por ejemplo). Cuando la url de la imagen en realidad es http://localhost/tuproyecto/images/aguaindex.gif
Para evitarte estos problemas, puedes simplemente ocupar paths relativos de las imágenes y no absolutos como lo haces actualmente.
En otras palabras, en vez de acceder a la imagen de esta forma:
.imgKax {
    background-image: url('/images/UsrKaxieBscr.png');
}

Lo hagas de la forma:
.imgKax {
    background-image: url('./../../images/UsrKaxieBscr.png');
}

Lógicamente deberás cambiar el path por la dirección relativa de tu imagen respecto al archivo de estilos css.

Muchas gracias! Me funcionó perfectamente. Gracias nuevamente :))))

@JiMena si la respuesta te resolvió el problema no olvides marcarla como aceptada.
